# R: ggplot better gradient color

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I am using ggplot to plot Proportional Stacked Bar plot. And the Plot I am getting is something like this:
[image]

And this is the self written function I am using:

```
df <- data.frame(id=letters[1:3],val0=1:3,val1=4:6,val2=7:9, val3=2:4, val4=1:3, val5=4:6, val6=10:12, val7=12:14)

PropBarPlot<-function(df, mytitle=""){
   melteddf<-melt(df, id=names(df)[1], na.rm=T)
   ggplot(melteddf, aes_string(x=names(df)[1], y="value", fill="variable")) + 
     geom_bar(position="fill") + 
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1)) + 
     labs(title=mytitle)
}

print(PropBarPlot(df))
```

**Here `val4` and `val5` are not very different.**

But due to colors some of them are not distinguishable. Can someone tell me how to choose better colors so that they are differentiable?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe to make it easier to test the plotting? Anyway, my idea is to have a look into scale_colour_brewer from ggplot, that allows you to use palettes from http://colorbrewer2.org

Comment: @zelite Added. Here basically `val4` and `val5` are not visibly very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @zelite and @SimonO101 for your help. This is simpler version of what both of you proposed. Adding here for the completeness.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(RColorBrewer)

getColors<-function(n){
   mypal<-colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(12, "Paired"))
   sample(mypal(n), n, replace=FALSE)
}

PropBarPlot<-function(df, mytitle=""){
   melteddf<-melt(df, id=names(df)[1], na.rm=T)
   n<-length(levels(factor(melteddf$variable)))

   ggplot(melteddf, aes_string(x=names(df)[1], y="value", fill="variable")) + 
      geom_bar(position="fill") + 
      scale_fill_manual(values=getColors(n)) + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1)) + 
      labs(title=mytitle)
}

df <- data.frame(id=letters[1:3],
             val0=1:3,
             val1=4:6,
             val2=7:9, 
             val3=2:4, 
             val4=1:3, 
             val5=4:6, 
             val6=10:12, 
             val7=12:14)

print(PropBarPlot(df))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

How about using `scale_fill_brewer` which makes use of colour palettes from the `ColorBrewer` website, implemented by the package `RColorBrewer`?

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut) ) +
geom_bar( ) +
scale_fill_brewer( type = "div" , palette = "RdBu" )
```

[image]

There are a number of different diverging palettes you can choose from.

```
require(RColorBrewer)
?brewer.pal
```

If you need more colours you can use the `colorRampPalette` features to interpolate between some colours (and I would use a `brewer.pal` palette for this). You can do this like so:

```
# Create a function to interpolate between some colours
mypal <- colorRampPalette( brewer.pal( 6 , "RdBu" ) )
# Run function asking for 19 colours
mypal(19)
 [1] "#B2182B" "#C2373A" "#D35749" "#E47658" "#F0936D" "#F4A989" "#F8BFA5"
 [8] "#FCD6C1" "#F3DDD0" "#E7E0DB" "#DAE2E6" "#CBE1EE" "#ADD1E5" "#90C0DB"
 [15] "#72AFD2" "#5B9DC9" "#478BBF" "#3478B5" "#2166AC"
```

In your example which requires 8 colours you an use it like this with `scale_fill_manual()`:

```
PropBarPlot<-function(df, mytitle=""){
   melteddf<-melt(df, id=names(df)[1], na.rm=T)
   ggplot(melteddf, aes_string(x=names(df)[1], y="value", fill="variable")) + 
     geom_bar(position="fill") + 
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1)) + 
     labs(title=mytitle)+
    scale_fill_manual( values = mypal(8) )
}

print(PropBarPlot(df))
```

Comment: I checked the different palettes, the best I get is a max of 12 variation, whereas in my case I need at-least 19 colors. With all the palettes, it is having problem.

Comment: @RachitAgrawal ok, I updated to something which might work for you. Check the edit.

Comment: Suffers from the same problem mentioned above. Some of them cannot be distinguished.

Comment: Then you have too many colour categories in a single plot! The palettes have a maximum number of colours for a reason. Consider splitting your plot using facet_wrap or facet_ grid.

Comment: Maybe it would work better if adjacent colors in the plot would be from oposite parts of the palete? In the example you have blues close to blues, and reds close to reds. If they alternate then it would be better distinguished? But I agree with SimonO101: if there's problem distinguishing so many colors, maybe you're plotting too much in one single plot.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing some code from @SimonO101

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(RColorBrewer)
mypal <- colorRampPalette( brewer.pal( 9 , "Set1" ) ) #you can try using different palete instead
#of "Set1" until it looks good to you

intercalate <- function(n){ #my crude attempt to shuffle the colors
  c(rbind(1:(n/2), n:(n/2+1))) #it will only work for even numbers
}

PropBarPlot<-function(df, mytitle=""){
  melteddf<-melt(df, id=names(df)[1], na.rm=T)
  ggplot(melteddf, aes_string(x=names(df)[1], y="value", fill="variable")) + 
    geom_bar(position="fill") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1)) + 
    labs(title=mytitle)+
    scale_fill_manual( values = mypal(8)[intercalate(8)] )
  #better would be to calculate the different number of categories
  #you have and put that instead of the number 8
}

df <- data.frame(id=letters[1:3],
                 val0=1:3,
                 val1=4:6,
                 val2=7:9, 
                 val3=2:4, 
                 val4=1:3, 
                 val5=4:6, 
                 val6=10:12, 
                 val7=12:14)

print(PropBarPlot(df))
```

See if that works better for your needs.

Comment: I have come up with a simpler solution to mix the colors. Added below. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use scale_fill_manual=c("red","green"), you can put more colors if you want
or
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Reds"), I like this one. You can use palettes here