# ggplot2: barplot with colors as a function of y-axis value

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have this simple code (data + barplot) :

```
dat <- c('Jan','Feb','Mar', 'Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec')
val <- c(-2.5, 3, 2.5, -3.3, -1, 0.2, 6, 4.3, 5.5, 2, -1.9, -2.3)
df <- data.frame(dat, val)
bar <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(dat, levels = month.abb), y = val)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
print(bar)
```

Elsewhere I created a heatmap using the following palette:

```
# Palette
LtoM <-colorRampPalette(c('red', 'yellow' ))
Mid <- "snow3"
MtoH <-colorRampPalette(c('lightgreen', 'darkgreen'))
```

that is called by:

```
scale_fill_gradient2(low = LtoM(100), mid = Mid, high = MtoH(100))
```

Now I would like to use a similar color palette for my barplot, that is I would like the color in each bar to be a function of the height (some grade from red for mimimum y to green for maximum y).

How can I do that, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're basically there with your current code. Just add the scale_fill_gradient function.

```
bar <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(dat, levels = month.abb), y = val, 
              fill=val)) +
       geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
       scale_fill_gradient2(low=LtoM(100), mid='snow3', 
       high=MtoH(100), space='Lab')
```

[image: custom colors]

However, allowing scale_fill_gradient2 to take care of the gradient-ing works pretty well

```
bar <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(dat, levels = month.abb), y = val, 
              fill=val)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
       scale_fill_gradient2(low='red', mid='snow3', high='darkgreen', space='Lab')
```

[image: generated colors]

Comment: thanks for replying lilster. actually i knew how to get your 1st graph, but is is not exactly what i'm after. i want all bars at say val = -2 be 'red' and 'green' when val = 5 (and a color scale in between). is it different than have each bar colored (uniformely) depending on the value it represents. i hope i'm a bit clearer now

Comment: I think I need more detail here.
'i want all bars at say val = -2 be 'red' and 'green' when val = 5 (and a color scale in between).' <- Both graphs I posted seem to satisfy this.
'is it different than have each bar colored (uniformely) depending on the value it represents.' <- That is different, but in my answers, neither colors are colored uniformly.
The scale fill gradient has set your minimum value to be the "reddest", your maximum value to be the "greenest", and then a color scale in between.
Can you describe how this is different to what you are seeking, perhaps with an image file attache

Comment: hello lilster thanks for youe patience :)   i would like to draw a plot 'like' this one http://www.quinn-curtis.com/QCChar96.jpg  you see, at any y value all bars are of the same color and the color is a function of y value.

Comment: There is no function which makes such a graph. The only workaround is to define lots of extremely small breaks and plot a stacked bar chart, as per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295440/r-ggplot-better-gradient-color