# Advanced coloring ggplot2 barplot: Two factor barplot with individual bars coloring based on values in vector

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, colorbrewer

Consider the following data frame for ggplot:

> cor.mt

```
o   variable    value
o   a   -0.5205695
p   a   -0.4940820
q   a   -0.5997149
r   a   0.4773977
s   a   -0.5473026
o   b   -0.5097157
p   b   -0.4837804
q   b   -0.5872109
r   b   0.4674440
s   b   -0.5358914
o   c   -0.5385717
p   c   -0.5111682
q   c   -0.6204540
r   c   0.4939069
s   c   -0.5662293
o   d   -0.5315217
p   d   -0.5044768
q   d   -0.6123321
r   d   0.4874416
s   d   -0.5588172
o   e   -0.6033193
p   e   -0.5726213
q   e   -0.6950456
r   e   0.5532849
s   e   -0.6343019
o   f   -0.4841113
p   f   -0.4594788
q   f   -0.5577137
r   f   0.4439631
s   f   -0.5089722
o   g   -0.4900397
p   g   -0.4651056
q   g   -0.5645435
r   g   0.4493998
s   g   -0.5152050
o   h   -0.5057246
p   h   -0.4799923
q   h   -0.5826129
r   h   0.4637839
s   h   -0.5316953
o   i   -0.4801576
p   i   -0.4557263
q   i   -0.5531589
r   i   0.4403372
s   i   -0.5048154
o   j   -0.5091269
p   j   -0.4832216
q   j   -0.5865326
r   j   0.4669041
s   j   -0.5352724
o   k   -0.4979368
p   k   -0.4726008
q   k   -0.5736411
r   k   0.4566419
s   k   -0.5235076
o   l   -0.5507836
p   l   -0.5227587
q   l   -0.6345226
r   l   0.5051061
s   l   -0.5790683
o   m   -0.5076627
p   m   -0.4818319
q   m   -0.5848458
r   m   0.4655613
s   m   -0.5337330
o   n   -0.5474711
p   n   -0.5196148
q   n   -0.6307065
r   n   0.5020683
s   n   -0.5755857
```

I will make a barplot using ggplot:

```
coul = brewer.pal(11, "RdYlBu")
coul = colorRampPalette(coul)(28)

p <- ggplot(cor.mt, aes(x=o, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
    theme_classic() +
    scale_fill_manual(values=coul) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

The output is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykU61.jpg

This is NOT what I want. I want all positive values (a:n for factor r) to be colored by 14 blue colors from the palette depending on the values of "variable", meaning the most positive value will be darkest blue, and the least positive value the lightest blue.

In addition, for negative values (a:n for factor o,p,q and s) I want the same thing, but in the red spectrum of the palette.

Comment: somewhat similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120194/ggplot2-barplot-with-colors-as-a-function-of-y-axis-value?rq=1. However, here its not two factors for the x-axis.

Comment: Maybe something from this package would help? https://github.com/clauswilke/multiscales