# How to vary color schemes for stacked barplot to highlight contrasts

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to make a stacked barplot in order to highlight contrasts.

However, using the methods I found, it always results in a smooth transition from one end of the color range to the other (e.g.: dark green to green to light green). This looks nice, but it is sometimes hard to read when you fill the bar with 10 different variables.

```
# example data
a <- c(rep(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 3)], 7))
b <- c(rep(1:2,10),1)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

You can see the effect

```
s <- ggplot(df, aes(b, fill=a))
s + geom_bar() + scale_fill_brewer()
```

[image: color transition]

For this example, it helps to use

```
 s + geom_bar() + scale_fill_brewer(type="div")
```

or

```
 s + geom_bar() + scale_colour_manual(values=c("#CC6666", "#7777DD"))
```

but if `a` has a lot of different values, you'll always see those "smooth color transitions".

[image]

Is there a way in `ggplot2` to "highlight differences" - like going from black to white to blue to yellow and so on ....

edit: I don't see why it has been marked as a duplicate. 1) the answer provided in the other questions is included in my question, but I am obviously looking for something different than the OP of the other question 2) I am looking for a color gradient that "highlights" the transition from one `fill` to another.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: ggplot better gradient color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295440/r-ggplot-better-gradient-color)

Comment: I didn't see this one. However, the solution posted there uses `scale_fill_brewer`, which is also part of my question (see above). This certainly does improve the result, but it does not highlight contrasts in any way.

Comment: Instead of `"div"`, try using `"qual"`, as in `scale_fill_brewer(type="qual")`

Comment: @BenBarnes thanks, this helps me a lot. However, sth strange occurs: some labels are labelled with the same colour [link](http://i.imgur.com/UojVQ5d.png)

Comment: you may have run out of colours in that palette.  I would try `scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")` ...

Comment: Thanks to both Ben and Ben ;-) The result is much better now. However, there are still similar colors next to each other, see green and blue [here](http://i.imgur.com/QgnAv22.png). I was using `+ scale_fill_brewer( type = "qual", palette="Paired")` But I guess there is no "quick solution" for this.